# Display word document in flutter app from url

Tags: firebase, flutter, pdf, docx

I have a docx file saved on firebase and I want to render this documnent in my app so not using an external app to open the document as a number of file libraries do. I have tried flutter_filereader which works perfect for a file on my phone however i cannot use it to open a url. Is this possible? I think converting it to a pdf would work as I can display those from a url, however I cannot find a library that will allow me to convert files to pdf before uploading to firebase?
Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple API call to `PdftronFlutter.openDocument`
Follow the this link https://www.pdftron.com/blog/flutter/build-a-document-viewer-in-flutter/. This blog said the usage of `PdftronFlutter`.

Comment: Does this only work for PDFs? Will I have to convert the docx to pdf first and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

You could display the url in-app using flutter_webview https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

Comment: Displaying a file from a firebase url just returns a blank white screen from flutter_webview, any idea why? Can display a normal webpage no problem

Comment: sorry, I have no idea on that